# Display full help text in python click

Tags: python, python-click

I am having the following problem and I am fearful there isn't a straghtforward way to solve it so I am asking here. I am using Click to implement a CLI and I have created several grouped commands under the main command. This is the code:

```
@click.group()
def main():
   pass

@main.command()
def getq():
    '''Parameters: --questionnaire_id, --question_id, --session_id, --option_id''' 
    click.echo('Question Answers')
```

When I type the main command alone in my terminal it lists all the subcommands with the help text next to each one. However, the text is not displayed fully for the case of getq. Instead, it displays only "Parameters: --questionnaire_id, --question_id,... ."
Is there a way to display it all?
Thank You

Comment: You will see the full help if you ask for help for that *specific* command: `yourcommand getq --help`. Help text is abbreviated for higher level help because there may be many commands and you want them to display nicely.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Of course, it's better to abbreviate. But, in my case it is required to display it fully. So is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use [the command's short_help argument](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/documentation/#command-short-help):

```py
@click.group()
def main():
   pass

@main.command(short_help='Parameters: --questionnaire_id, --question_id, --session_id, --option_id')
def getq():
    click.echo('Question Answers')
```

If you insist to use the docstring for this and want to override the automatic shortening of it, then you could use a custom Group class overriding the `format_commands` method to directly use `cmd.help` instead of the `get_short_help_str` method:

```py
import click
from gettext import gettext as _


class FullHelpGroup(click.Group):
    def format_commands(self, ctx: click.Context, formatter: click.HelpFormatter) -> None:
        """Extra format methods for multi methods that adds all the commands
        after the options.
        """
        commands = []
        for subcommand in self.list_commands(ctx):
            cmd = self.get_command(ctx, subcommand)
            # What is this, the tool lied about a command.  Ignore it
            if cmd is None:
                continue
            if cmd.hidden:
                continue

            commands.append((subcommand, cmd))

        # allow for 3 times the default spacing
        if len(commands):
            limit = formatter.width - 6 - max(len(cmd[0]) for cmd in commands)

            rows = []
            for subcommand, cmd in commands:
                help = cmd.help if cmd.help is not None else ""
                rows.append((subcommand, help))

            if rows:
                with formatter.section(_("Commands")):
                    formatter.write_dl(rows)


@click.group(cls=FullHelpGroup)
def main():
   pass


@main.command()
def getq():
    '''Parameters: --questionnaire_id, --question_id, --session_id, --option_id'''
    click.echo('Question Answers')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You most probably want to override the `max_content_width` (at most 80 columns by default) also. You could do this by overriding the context settings:

```py
import shutil


@click.group(cls=FullHelpGroup,
             context_settings={'max_content_width': shutil.get_terminal_size().columns - 10})
def main():
   pass
```

Comment: Ook. Thank you a bunch. I am fine with short_help since it works!